# How to set event onclick listview (multiple listview) in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm android beginner. I have 3 tab control (each tab control have list view).
class Active I has function :

```
 @Override

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        TextView link=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        link.setText("Hot news >> "+lv_arr[position]);
        LinearLayout llo=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lout_link);
        Button bt_link=new Button(this);
        bt_link.setText("test");
        llo.addView(bt_link);
    }
```

It just working with `listview` (first tabcontrol, listview in other tabcontrol it not working).
So how set event `onclick` listview in second, third tabcotrol? .
Thanks very very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can set 3 different `onClickListeners` for three lists.

Please use following:

```
list1.setOnclickListener(list1ClickListener);
list2.setOnclickListener(list2ClickListener);
list3.setOnclickListener(list3ClickListener);
```

---

And the `listItemClickLiteners`:

```
/*Item click listener for the list1 item click event.*/
    final private transient OnItemClickListener list1ClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

        /*(non-Javadoc)
         * @see
         * android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener#onItemClick(android
         * .widget.AdapterView, android.view.View, int, long) */

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                final int position, final long itemID) {
            }

/*Item click listener for the list2 item click event.*/
    final private transient OnItemClickListener list2ClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                final int position, final long itemID) {
            }

/*Item click listener for the list3 item click event.*/
    final private transient OnItemClickListener list3ClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                final int position, final long itemID) {
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Shirikants answer works.(just need to add a few braces)

```
    /* Item click listener for the list1 item click event. */
private transient OnItemClickListener list1ClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener#onItemClick(android
     * .widget.AdapterView, android.view.View, int, long)
     */

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
            final int position, final long itemID) {
    }
};

/* Item click listener for the list2 item click event. */
private transient OnItemClickListener list2ClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
            final int position, final long itemID) {
    }
};

/* Item click listener for the list3 item click event. */
private transient OnItemClickListener list3ClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
            final int position, final long itemID) {
    }
};
```